# How to add new elements to the objects array from the submit event handler

Tags: javascript, arrays, dom, submit, addeventlistener

Hello coder i was trying to make a simple javascript todo app and i've already setup some stuff but now im stuck at 'how can i add a new element to the todos array of objects from the `addEventListener('submit', function(e){}`
to make u understand what i wanna do more i leave this code down below of my todo app:

```
//The array im working with

const todos = [{
    text: 'wake up',
    completed: true
}, {
    text: 'get some food',
    completed: true
}, {
    text: 'play csgo',
    completed: false
}, {
    text: 'play minecraft',
    completed: true
}, {
    text: 'learn javascript',
    completed: false
}];

//looping to create new p elements on the html for todos

todos.forEach(function(todo){
    let p = document.createElement('p');
    p.textContent = todo.text;
    document.querySelector('#todo').appendChild(p);
})

//the eventListener that i want to make add new .text property to the todo array inside a new object

document.querySelector('#form').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
todos.push(e.target.elements.firstName.value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have an array of objects with 'text' and 'completed' properties, you will need to push a new object with that structure onto your array.

```
const newObject = {text: e.target.elements.firstName.value, completed: false};
todos.push(newObject);
```

or if you want to condense it a bit:

```
todos.push({text: e.target.elements.firstName.value, completed: false});
```

Comment: i tried it but it has a problem it doesnt actually add a new element to the page

Comment: i've uploaded the full code with the html file to github if you wanna check it out 
https://github.com/salahmak/Todo-application

Answer (score 1):

Value to add

```
let value = e.target.elements.firstName.value,
object = {'text': value, 'completed':true }; 

todos.push(object);
```

Comment: this is the shortest solution that i was thinking of but didnt know how to write it well
thanks dude

Comment: but still doesnt work on the page it doesn't add a new p element to the page
you can check the page here on this ngrok link  [link] ( 8e83ae80.ngrok.io)

Comment: check out the github repository of this app : [ github.com/salahmak/Todo-application ]

Answer (score 1):

Create a function that adds a task given its parameters, which in your case would look like this:

```
function addTask(name, completed) {
    let p = document.createElement('p');
    p.textContent = name;
    document.querySelector('#todo').appendChild(p);
}
```

If you ever need to change the implementation, it will be well-contained in this function.

Then, when you need to **add a new task** (in this case in the submit handler), you just have to call the function:

```
document.querySelector('#form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    var title = document.querySelector('input[type="text"]').value;
    addTask(title, false);
});
```

Abstracting your objectives in functions gives you benefits, like a more organized code, so as a bonus, you can now simplify how you create the very first tasks:

```
const todos = [{
    text: 'wake up',
    completed: true
}, {
    text: 'get some food',
    completed: true
}];

todos.forEach(function(todo) {
    addTask(todo.text);
})
```

Comment: same :(  doesn't add a new p element to the html page you can check it out here and i can upload the whole code of the app on github
you can check the page here [link] ( 8e83ae80.ngrok.io)

Comment: check out the github repository of this app : [ https://github.com/salahmak/Todo-application ]

Comment: Your github code works perfectly. Writing something and clicking "submit" adds the task at the bottom as expected. Maybe try a different browser?